# How to fix Parse error: syntax error,unexpected ";' (T_Encapsed_AND_WHITESPACE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Tags: php, parsing, whitespace

I don't where I'm going wrong. I keep getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error,unexpected ";' (T_Encapsed_AND_WHITESPACE) in C:\xampp\htdocs...

This line is where it seems like where the error located.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `memberinfo` WHERE `memberid` = '".$mymemberid."'"' ;
```

Full code:

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="memberaccess"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="memberin"; // Table name 

//Declare $mymemberid as the data is submitted in the form under the "memberid" field    
 $mymemberid = ($_POST['memberid']);

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

//select the row in the table that matches the passed variable from the form    submission
$query="SELECT * FROM `memberinfo` WHERE `memberid` = '".$mymemberid."'"' ; 

$result=mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    die(mysql_error());
}

// assign mySQL values from table to php variables

$balance=mysql_result($result,1,"balance");
$fname=mysql_result($result,1,"FirstName");
$lname=mysql_result($result,1,"LastName");
$address=mysql_result($result,1,"address");
$city=mysql_result($result,1,"city");
$email=mysql_result($result,1,"email");

//close the mySQL connection        
mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: Default formatting shows you the hint!! remove the extra ' from query variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix this line:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `memberinfo` WHERE `memberid` = '".$mymemberid."'"' ;
```

to this

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `memberinfo` WHERE `memberid` = '".$mymemberid."'";
```

Additional hints:

- don't use mysql_*  - instead use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
- escape you params with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)! => read about [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Answer (score 0):

You have error in sql query

Try This

```
"SELECT * FROM `memberinfo` WHERE `memberid` = '".$mymemberid."'";
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks

Comment: yup anytime mate !!!!